# Why apt-get purge wants to remove non matching packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, purge

I guess it's all about dependecy management but needed to be sure. My case:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

> The following packages will be REMOVED:   nvidia-352* nvidia-cg-dev*
>   nvidia-cg-toolkit* nvidia-opencl-icd-352*   nvidia-prime*
>   nvidia-settings* retroarch*

Hey, leave my `retroarch` alone, was my reaction. Any way to avoid it or just to go along with it and reinstall `retroarch` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retroarch` depends on `nvidia-cg-toolkit` so it gets removed if you remove `nvidia-cg-toolkit`.

As a side note `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` most likely doesn't do what you want:

First the shell will try to expand `nvidia*`. So if you have for example a file named `nvidia.txt` in your current folder the shell will actually run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia.txt
```

If the shell can't expand `nvidia*` `apt-get` will interpret it as a regular expression (not a shell pattern!) meaning "`nvidi` followed by zero or more `a`" and then search for packages with names containing a matching substring. 
That is `apt-get` will purge all packages with a name containing `nvidi` (without the `a` because the "zero" in "zero or more").

Better use

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*'
```

for all package containing `nvidia` or

```
sudo apt-get purge '^nvidia.*'
```

if you want to remove all packages starting with `nvidia`.